# How to get the number which repeated the fewest times in array?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

How to get the number which repeated the fewest times ?

For example:

- from [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,2,3,4,6] return [1] because "1" is only repeated onces while others are repeated 2 or more times.
- from [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,2,3,4] return [2,6] because both "2" and "6" are only repeated twice instead of three or more times for other numbers.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for. what constitutes the "repeat number"? It seems like you want to return 1 from the first line, but 1 doesn't repeat at all. Can you give a little more in your description to explain the problem more thoroughly?

Comment: Wow, I don't get it. Shouldn't the first return [2] and the second return [1]? Or [1,2,3,4,6]?  This is drastically underspecified and while it's great that you provided examples they seem to just increase the confusion...

Comment: I think the means the number that's repeated the fewest times.

Comment: @Why do you mean the smallest number that is repeated the least number of times (which would make sense of first example) or just the numbers that are repeated the least number of times (i.e. your not worried about the smallest number but the least repeated number(s) only???

Comment: You second example has only one 5 in it, so shouldn't it return [5] for that?

Comment: The question is way better than it was at first, but still not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
a.group_by{|e| a.count(e)}.min[1].uniq
```

---

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :040 > a =  [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,6,6,2,3,4]
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :041 > a.group_by{|e| a.count(e)}.min[1].uniq
 => [2, 6] 

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :044 > a =   [1,2,3,4,6,6,2,3,4,6]
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :045 > a.group_by{|e| a.count(e)}.min[1].uniq
 => [1]
```

**Update: O(n) time**

```
def least_frequent(a)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  a.each{|e| counts[e] += 1}
  least =[nil, []]
  counts.each do |k,v|
    if least[0].nil?
      least[0] = v
      least[1] = k
    elsif v < least[0]
      least[0] = v
      least[1] = [k]
    elsif v == least[0]
      least[1] << k
    end
  end
  least[1]
end
```

Here are benchmarks(running this test 10,000 times) between the first and second method:

```
             user     system      total        real
first   10.950000   0.020000  10.970000 ( 10.973345)
better   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.511417)
```

with an array set to:

```
a =  [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,6,6,2,3,4] * 10
```

Comment: This is `O(n^2)` so it will be really slow for big arrays. Ideally, it would be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,2,3,4]
a.group_by{|i| a.count(i) }
#=> {1=>[5], 2=>[2, 2, 6, 6], 3=>[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]}
```

And then pick from that Hash as to what you want (the hash's key is the number of items)

Comment: This is ok for short arrays, but it is O(len(a)^2), because of a.count

Answer (score 1):

```
>> h = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,2,3,4].inject(Hash.new(0)) { |x,y| x[y]+=1;x }.select{|x,y| y>1 }
=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>3, 6=>2}
>> h.values.min
=> 2
>> h.each{|x,y| puts "#{x} #{y}" if y==h.values.min }
2 2
6 2
=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>3, 6=>2}
>>
```